# How to set proxy for JWT decoders withJwkSetUri or else request times out

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt

Hi All so I have a setup where is pass a Azure AD Access token from frontend to backend(Springboot) and in the backend I validate the token (OAuth2 Authorization server) and then provide access to API endpoints . This is my current setup.

***SecurityConfig.java***

```
package com.devops.Portal.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidatorResult;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/7521acbc-a68c-41e5-a975-1cf83066dd19/discovery/v2.0/keys").build();
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>(
                JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer("https://login.microsoftonline.com/7521acbc-a68c-41e5-a975-1cf83066dd19/discovery/v2.0/keys"),
                new CustomTokenValidator()
        ));
        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    private static class CustomTokenValidator implements OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>{

        public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt jwt){
            if(jwt.getSubject() == null || jwt.getSubject().isEmpty()){
                return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure();
            }else{
                return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder());
    }
}
```

But the request times out because im behind a proxy.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://login.microsoftonline.com/asds6d8atsd7ats7dta8sdt/discovery/v2.0/keys": Connection timed out: connect;
```

So if i have tried the following steps to attach a proxy

```
 @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();
        httpClient = httpClient.proxy(typeSpec -> typeSpec.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host("http.proxy.example.com").port(8000));
        return httpClient;
    }

    ReactorClientHttpConnector conn = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient());

    @Bean
    public ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder (){
        return NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/asds6d8atsd7ats7dta8sdt/discovery/v2.0/keys").webClient(WebClient.builder().clientConnector(conn).build()).build();
    }
```

but I get a error on this line which says

```
**http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder());**
```

[image]

How can i pass **reactiveNimbusDecoder** in my decoder method.
I'm a complete newbie to OAuth and authorization ,so any guidance will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the following VM arguments to set the proxy URL and Port for Java:

```bash
    -Dhttp.proxyHost=<your_proxy_host>
    -Dhttp.proxyPort=<your_proxy_port>
    -Dhttps.proxyHost=<your_proxy_host>
    -Dhttps.proxyPort=<your_proxy_port>
```

The reason it won't let you use a Reactive decoder is because the Reactive part implies a whole different concept ( https://projectreactor.io/ ). A standard NimbusJwtDecoder is the one you need, but to customize the HttpClient that it uses, you need to use it's restOperations method on it's builder:

```java
    private static void configureOauth2(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> resourceServerConfigurer) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

        requestFactory.setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("http.proxy.example.com", 1234));

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

        resourceServerConfigurer.jwt(
            jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(new OidcAuthenticationConverter())
                .decoder(NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("jwk-set-uri").restOperations(restTemplate).build()));
    }
```

Keep in that this is just a quick sample on how to create a client factory and proxy, you can customize that however you want to, but the main thing is to pass whatever RestTemplate you created with your proxy to the rest operations method of the NimbusJwtDecoderBuilder.

Both solutions work, but if you only want your decoder to use the proxy, use the latter one.